# Campaign Monitor Template -

Tags: html, css, email, newsletter

When trying to create a template using Campaign Monitor, then they offer a [starting template](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/create/editable-content/). But the code is *terrible*! I've figured most of it out, - but I can't figure out what the thought is behind these classes here:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    table[class=w0], td[class=w0] {
        width: 0 !important;
    }

    table[class=w10], td[class=w10], img[class=w10] {
        width: 10px !important;
    }

    table[class=w15], td[class=w15], img[class=w15] {
        width: 5px !important;
    }

    table[class=w30], td[class=w30], img[class=w30] {
        width: 10px !important;
    }

    table[class=w60], td[class=w60], img[class=w60] {
        width: 10px !important;
    }

    table[class=w125], td[class=w125], img[class=w125] {
        width: 80px !important;
    }

    table[class=w130], td[class=w130], img[class=w130] {
        width: 55px !important;
    }

    table[class=w140], td[class=w140], img[class=w140] {
        width: 90px !important;
    }

    table[class=w160], td[class=w160], img[class=w160] {
        width: 180px !important;
    }

    table[class=w170], td[class=w170], img[class=w170] {
        width: 100px !important;
    }

    table[class=w180], td[class=w180], img[class=w180] {
        width: 80px !important;
    }

    table[class=w195], td[class=w195], img[class=w195] {
        width: 80px !important;
    }

    table[class=w220], td[class=w220], img[class=w220] {
        width: 80px !important;
    }

    table[class=w240], td[class=w240], img[class=w240] {
        width: 180px !important;
    }

    table[class=w255], td[class=w255], img[class=w255] {
        width: 185px !important;
    }

    table[class=w275], td[class=w275], img[class=w275] {
        width: 135px !important;
    }

    table[class=w280], td[class=w280], img[class=w280] {
        width: 135px !important;
    }

    table[class=w300], td[class=w300], img[class=w300] {
        width: 140px !important;
    }

    table[class=w325], td[class=w325], img[class=w325] {
        width: 95px !important;
    }

    table[class=w360], td[class=w360], img[class=w360] {
        width: 140px !important;
    }

    table[class=w410], td[class=w410], img[class=w410] {
        width: 180px !important;
    }

    table[class=w470], td[class=w470], img[class=w470] {
        width: 200px !important;
    }

    table[class=w580], td[class=w580], img[class=w580] {
        width: 280px !important;
    }

    table[class=w640], td[class=w640], img[class=w640] {
        width: 300px !important;
    }

    table[class=hide], td[class=hide], img[class=hide], p[class=hide], span[class=hide], .hide {
        display: none !important;
    }

    table[class=h0], td[class=h0] {
        height: 0 !important;
    }

    p[class=footer-content-left] {
        text-align: center !important;
    }

    #headline p {
        font-size: 30px !important;
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how it's being used:

```
<layout label="Image and text">
  <table class="w580 section__container tema__container" width="580" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="w580" width="580">
        <img editable="true" label="Image" class="w580" width="580" border="0">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="w580" width="580">
        <p align="left" class="article-title">
          <singleline label="Title">Add a title</singleline>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="w580" width="580">
        <div align="left" class="article-content">
          <multiline label="Description">Enter your description</multiline>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</layout>
```

Those classes are only mentioned in the `(max-device-width: 480px)`-part of the code and no other place. Is it because these styles are redundant on desktop devices?

This makes good enough sense for me:

```
table[class=w10], td[class=w10], img[class=w10] {
        width: 10px !important;
    }
```

But I'm unable to see the logic in the naming of this:

```
table[class=w125], td[class=w125], img[class=w125] {
        width: 80px !important;
    }
```

Comment: why use attribute selectors for classes?  it means that if your element has multiple classes, the way your attribute selector has been set up, it won't work

Comment: @Pete, As the OP stated, this was downloaded from Campaign Monitor, not coded by them.

Comment: @Digital_Frankenstein as this is a general question about the code (actually I don't even know what the question is - there doesn't seem to be one), the above comment is a general observation about it and I agree with the OP that it is terrible.  Also where do I state in my comment that the OP wrote this code?  Don't know why you feel the need to @ me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That template looks quite old as the industry has moved passed attribute selectors and to direct class definitions.
i.e.: .classname {} as opposed to table[class=classname] {}

I would seriously consider using one of these resources as they're maintained frequently by people heavily invested and vocal in the industry:

1. https://tedgoas.github.io/Cerberus/ - Great starter templates which incorporate your general content types.
2. https://github.com/leemunroe/responsive-html-email-template - Same as above and equally as good.
3. https://templates.mailchimp.com/ - A good resource for email overall, not just code.
4. https://litmus.com/community/snippets - great for smaller snippets like background images or Outlook specific code.